# MFP - How to load test Mobile Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can someone please suggest me any tool that can be used for Mobile App load testing build in MobileFirst Platform 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good article to use JMeter for performance testing of Adapters:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/12/20/mfp-performance-testing-session-independent-mode/

They even provide the files at the end of the article.

Comment: The Sample application is incomplete. It does not have the complete application with runtime for (test-android-1.0)

Comment: I used my own runtime application - as I assumed most people would.  The important part is the .jmx test plan that is setup for you.  Calling your own runtime and adapter is easy to do.  You are correct though - it does come with a test .wlapp in the .zip file, but it is just the end result (.wlapp) and not the source-code.  Drop Nir Grande an email and ask him if he can add that to the zip file....

Comment: I also wrote an article http://tonyisageek.blogspot.co.uk/p/mobilefirst-v71-oauth-jmeter.html that may also help as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing for *the application*? Surely you mean the server/adapters...

For this you can use a tool such as jMeter to simulate a large amount of adapter requests to the server and see how your setup behaves.